# How to add cover pages to rmarkdown pdf file?

Tags: pdf, r, markdown

I need to add a coverpage at the very begginning and end of a pdf document i have made using R Markdown. (My first time using R markdown and latex)

As it is now, the first page of the file output is the table of contens.

My header is as follows:

```
---
title: "TIMSS Rapport, Field trial"
date: "25 Juli 2019"
header-includes:
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[english, danish]{babel}
geometry: margin=1.9cm
fontsize: 12pt
line-height: 1.5
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["tcolorbox", "float"]
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
classoption: a4paper
---
```

Question 1) How do i make make a page at the very beginning and end? (Different pages)

Question 2) I would like these pages to have an image as background, and place a textbox on top of the background - any ideas about how to do this?

I have tried options below, without any luck:

````
---
title: "TIMSS Rapport, Field trial"
include-before-body: "O:\\ARTS_TIMSS-2019\\elever.jpg"
output:
  pdf_document:
---

and

---
title: "TIMSS Rapport, Field trial"
include-before-body: "O:\\ARTS_TIMSS-2019\\elever.jpg"
output:
  pdf_document:
      include-before-body: "O:\\ARTS_TIMSS-2019\\elever.jpg"
---

and adding these options below the yaml header:

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

```{r echo=FALSE, fig.align='center', fig.pos='B'}
knitr::include_graphics('item6.png')

\end{titlepage}
````

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389149/add-image-in-title-page-of-rmarkdown-pdf help?